# Selenium opens new browser instance (Brave Browser)

Tags: python, selenium, brave-browser

absolute noob here but I recently started a python automation project which checks the day of the week, and if it's a weekday it should open a browser with my college schedule for example, and if it's a weekend day it should open up different websites.

I use the brave browser as my default browser but I was wondering if it is possible to open up my regular browser profile when I run my code instead of the new instance where it does not have all my bookmarks and passwords?

Thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import datetime

day = datetime.datetime.now()
dag = day.weekday()
def Testing():
    if dag >= 5:
        return Weekend()
    else:
        return Weekday()


def Weekend():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    ## options.add_argument("/Users/vadim/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser")
    options.binary_location = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
    driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
    driver.get('https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox')
    Outlook_Aanmelden = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/aside/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a')
    Outlook_Aanmelden.click()
    Email_Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]')
    Email_Field.send_keys('@live.com')
    Outlook_Volgende = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    Outlook_Volgende.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Password_Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
    Password_Field.send_keys('pass')
    Password_Field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    Inlog_Outlook = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    Inlog_Outlook.click()

    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://youtube.com');")

def Weekday():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    ## options.add_argument("/Users/vadim/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser")
    options.binary_location = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
    driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
    driver.get('https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox')
    Outlook_Aanmelden = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/aside/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a')
    Outlook_Aanmelden.click()
    Email_Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]')
    Email_Field.send_keys('@live.com')
    Outlook_Volgende = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    Outlook_Volgende.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Password_Field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
    Password_Field.send_keys('pass')
    Password_Field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    Inlog_Outlook = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    Inlog_Outlook.click()

    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://youtube.com');")

Testing()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using webbrowser instead of selenium, it's part of the python standard library so you should already have it.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Here's the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/webbrowser.html) if you wan't to play around with it.